# Does the "Impact" weapon proficiency increase all damage?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

According to the CoD wiki and the game itself, [Impact](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Impact) only increases damage through surfaces (in a similar manner to Deep Impact and FMJ from previous games).  However, I seem to be experiencing higher damage overall.  It seems that a single burst from my M16 will now take down an enemy with ease as opposed to the 2 or 3 I had to use before using Impact.

Is this a bug, a description error, or am I imagining this behavior?

Comment: is it possible the recoil is pointing the barrel upwards and you end up getting inadvertent headshots?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer**

It increases damage indirectly.

**Longer answer**

This has been a common occurrence since Modern Warfare I.  The 'impact' weapon perk is similar to the 'deep impact' in the first one.  While it doesn't actually increase the damage **directly**, there are a couple important scenarios to note here that could cause your weapon to do more damage.

***The first:***

Chances are you're shooting through surfaces more then you realize and the increased penetration is actually making your gun stronger.  Most Call of Duty fights take place around some sort of cover (unless they are a total noob and roam the middle of the street avoiding potential cover) and while you're carefully aiming at their head or chest chances are you're going to miss and utilize your bullet penetration.

***The Second:***

Aah, the multi-kill.  My favorite reason to throw on 'impact'.  In Call of Duty, players are considered a 'surface', meaning that if two players were standing in a line and you shot the first one, the penetrating bullets would hit the second player for less damage then the first.  Putting on 'Impact' can be the difference between clearing a room of four players and only killing the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think it only increases damage when shooting through surfaces.

Comment: Please don't post answers unless you add a source. This is a guess, not a fact; therefor not a reliable answer.

Answer (score -1):

personal idea.

without impact proficiency:

bullet (normal damage) >>>> penetrable surface >>>> bullet (less damage) >>>> enemy

with impact proficiency:

bullet (normal damage) >>>> penetrable surface >>>> bullet (normal damage) >>>> enemy

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by this, and sources to back this claim up?